# How do I make the click function on my carousel work when items are appended?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, carousel

I have a (very raw) test site up at http://belmontfeed.com/site/ where I am trying to get the vertical carousel on the right to control the photo on the left.

The Previous/Next buttons work fine, and generally clicking on a carousel item will load the photo associated with it, but whenever I allowWrap on the carousel the click no longer functions.

I believe it is because the appending/prepending messes up the count that the click function is based off of, but I am fairly new to jQuery and am not sure where to turn.

The complete code should be viewable on the above site. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
if ( opts.allowWrap !== false ) {
  // prepend and append extra slides so we don't see any empty space when we
  // near the end of the carousel.  for fluid containers, add even more clones
  // so there is plenty to fill the screen
  // @todo: optimize this based on slide sizes
  opts.slides.slice(0, opts.slideCount).clone().css( slideCSS ).appendTo( wrap );
  if ( opts.carouselVisible === undefined )
     opts.slides.slice(0, opts.slideCount).clone().css( slideCSS ).appendTo( wrap );
  opts.slides.slice(0, opts.slideCount).clone().css( slideCSS ).prependTo( wrap );
  if ( opts.carouselVisible === undefined )
     opts.slides.slice(0, opts.slideCount).clone().css( slideCSS ).prependTo( wrap );

  wrap.find('.cycle-slide-active').removeClass('cycle-slide-active');
  opts.slides.eq(opts.startingSlide).addClass('cycle-slide-active');
}
```

**UPDATE:** The most direct click function code is as follows:

```
$('#cycle-2 .cycle-slide').click(function(){ 
    var index = ($('#cycle-2').data('cycle.API').getSlideIndex(this)-8);   
    slideshows.cycle('goto', index); 
});
```

I added a ghetto fix of just subtracting the count by 8 (as that is the number of prepends) but it stops functioning once it reaches number 8 until it auto rotates back to one. A more sustainable fix would be lovely...

Comment: **UPDATE:** Upon further inspection it seems the auto-rotate function is no longer triggering a change in photo either, I'm assuming these are being cause by the same issue?

Comment: So where is this click function ?

Comment: `$('#cycle-2 .cycle-slide').click(function(){ var index = ($('#cycle-2').data('cycle.API').getSlideIndex(this)-8); slideshows.cycle('goto', index); });` That is the most direct click function, I added a ghetto fix of just subtracting the count by 8 (as that is the number of prepends) but it stops functioning once it reaches number 8 until it auto rotates back to one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! By taking my quick fix and switching the operator from '-' to '%,' I was able to achieve the results I wanted. To set it to a dynamic number I will just swap the eight out for a variable representing the number of looped posts.

```
$('#cycle-2 .cycle-slide').click(function(){ 
    var index = ($('#cycle-2').data('cycle.API').getSlideIndex(this)%8);   
    slideshows.cycle('goto', index); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. This does work to a degree. The only negative is that it scrolls back to the top of the slides when clicking any of the appended slides – rather than continuing to scroll in the same direction. Curious if there's a way to prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

Using the new spec for jquery, you can call

```
$(document).on('click', '.cycle-carousel-wrap > div', function(e) {...});
```

This way, jquery finds the object each time, regardless of whether it's been modified/appended/etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Jeremy, thanks so much for the response! Unfortunately, I am still getting used to jQuery and am not entirely sure how to integrate this into the script. Any chance you could explain it any further? Sorry to be a burden.

Comment: i used a ghetto fix of subtracting the post count by 8 (the number of prepends) which gets the clicks to work up until the 8th one where it must wait to reset. is there anyway to modify this slightly to make it work? `$('#cycle-2 .cycle-slide').click(function(){ var index = ($('#cycle-2').data('cycle.API').getSlideIndex(this)-8); slideshows.cycle('goto', index); });`